# Password protect vhost virtual document root

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2, password-protected

I have the following setup for automatically generating subdomains/virtual document roots configured in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (running on Debian 7.0)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/htdocs/%1

    # Setup correct (virtual) document root as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for PHP
    php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /home/jbraun/setdocroot.php

    <Directory /home/%2/htdocs/%1>
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

            # These lines don't work
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "HALMA"
            AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
            Require valid-user
            # Commented for testing purposes only
            # Allow from halma.lan
            # Satisfy any

    </Directory>

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhost_access.log combined
```

### What is working and what it is all about

The above configuration allows users to creates subdirectories under their `/home/username/htdocs/` directory and access them in the browser by a dynamically generated subdomain, e.g. the folder `/home/jbraun/htdocs/project` will be accessible at `http://project.jbraun.halma.lan` (where `halma.lan` is the local intranet name, corresponding DNS is setup and working). Furthermore the whole story is accessible via DynDNS service at similar URLs like `project.jbraun.foobar.dyndns.org` from the outside world.

### What I want to achieve and is not working

I would like to have access from the local network (`halma.lan` or let's say `192.168.2.*`) without password protection while access from WAN coming via a DynDNS URL (`project.jbraun.foobar.dyndns.org`) should be password protected.

Thus I followed the Apache docs and added the "Auth*" lines

```
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "HALMA"
       AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
       Require valid-user
```

but unfortunately nothing happens (yes I have restarted apache in the meantime). The server's error logfile is silent, too.

When I add the same lines in some of my projects .htaccess files everything works as excpected, so I assume there must be some issues with the VirtualDocumentRoot and/or dynamically generated file paths in the configuration.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, how I could accomplish this or if it is possible at all?

Thanks a lot in advance.

*** [EDIT] ***

I'd like to post the configuration that worked in the end, just for reference and other people searching for this issue:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias *.*.halma.lan
        ServerAlias *.*.foobar.dyndns.org
        UseCanonicalName Off
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%2/htdocs/%1

        # Setup correct (virtual) document root as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for PHP
        php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /home/jbraun/setdocroot.php

        #<Directory /home/%2/htdocs/%1>
        <Directory ~ "^/home/.*/htdocs/.*/">

                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "HALMA"
                AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
                Require valid-user
                Allow from 10.0.0
                Satisfy Any
        </Directory>

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/vhost_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks to HBruijn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is safe to say the `%1` and `%2` expansions only happen within the few [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) directives that support such magic.

This may be an example where the slightly less secure `Location` directive can be used to contain the authentication directives i.e.

```
<Location />
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "HALMA"
   AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
   Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Alternatively, a [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) directive may also contain regular expressions, allowing something like:

```
<Directory ~ "^/home/.*/htdocs/.*/">

</Directory>
```

Which you can improve by adding a regular expression that matches your username naming conventions e.g. `"^/home/([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})/htdocs/.*/"`

Comment: Using regex in Directory along with a few other tweaks concerning Require, Allow from and Satisfy did the whole trick. Amazing whats possible with a little bit of config magic :) Thanks for the comprehensive answer..